# ASP NET How to show part of page depenting on some condition?

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, web

I would like to ask, how can I change (show or hide) part of the same web page according to some condition, like in PHP?
E.g. I would like to hide log-in formular if user has sent submit button and password was correct.
I've seen this technique used in PHP and it looks like:

```
<?php 
    if (! $logged_in) {
        //<form> ... </form>
?>

//...some common content...

<?php
    }
    else {
    //<p> ... </p>
?>
```

Is there any way in ASP.NET using C# how to 'recycle' pages like in PHP?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for [Razor syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-c)

Example:

```
@{
   if (logged_in)
   {
     <form>...</form>
   }
   else
   {
     <form>...</form>
   }
}
```

or:

```
 @if (!logged_in)
 {
   <form>...</form>
 }
 else
 {
   <form>...</form>
 }
```

Comment: This might be just what I ment. Thank you very much.